# What does this text mean?

Tags: character-identification

I work in an Irish speaking school. There are no Chinese people or people of Asian ethnicity in the school and there are no Chinese language classes or Asian culture clubs or anything like that. Today I walked into an empty classroom to find the following on the board. It seems to be traditional 極女戈? I can’t find the last character anywhere. What does this mean ? A name ? The phrase doesn’t show anything online. Maybe a google transliteration of an English name ??? Ji nu ge dou ?

[image]

Comment: It's nonsense. I also can't understand the fourth glyph (if it's a glyph at all). Judging from the wrong strokes (especially the broken stroke of 又 in 極), whoever wrote this does not seem to be a regular Chinese user.

Comment: @LParker I thought the fourth character might have been an attempt at 斗

Comment: Consider the possibility that they were trying to imitate Japanese. The fourth glyph looks a bit like ぐ (but 戈ぐ is not a word AFAIK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Chinese. I carefully watched the characters you showed us. I have no idea what “极女戈” means. I take it as characters which were randomly wrote together. There is no meaning in it.

Comment: Thank you Jie Zhu  多谢